# Merging data frames on dyadic variables in both

Tags: r, merge

I wish to merge two dataframes based on dyads in each (*sibA* and *sibB* in *df1* and *df2* below).

```
sibA = c(1,2,13,4,6) 
sibB = c(11,12,3,14,16) 
mum = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", NA) 
df1 = data.frame(sibA, sibB, mum)    
df1
#  sibA sibB  mum
# 1    1   11   aa
# 2    2   12   bb
# 3   13    3   cc
# 4    4   14   dd
# 5    6   16 <NA>

sibA = c(1,12,3,14,22,23)
sibB = c(11,2,13,4,32,33)
inbredCoeffsibA = c(.1,.12,.3,.14,.22,.23)
inbredCoeffsibB = c(.11,.2,.13,.4,.32,.33)
df2 = data.frame(sibA, sibB, inbredCoeffsibA, inbredCoeffsibB)
df2
#   sibA sibB inbredCoeffsibA inbredCoeffsibB
# 1    1   11            0.10            0.11
# 2   12    2            0.12            0.20
# 3    3   13            0.30            0.13
# 4   14    4            0.14            0.40
# 5   22   32            0.22            0.32
# 6   23   33            0.23            0.33
```

The problem is that the order in which each of the members of a dyad in the variables in both data frames is arbitrary (eg: the siblings 2-12 dyad is reversed in *df2*, and 3-13 is reversed in *df1*). Desired outcome data frame:

```
sibA =c(1,12,3,14,22,23,6)
sibB = c(11,2,13,4,32,33,16)
mum = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", NA, NA,NA)
inbredCoeffsibA= c(.1,.12,.3,.14,.22,.23,NA)
inbredCoeffsibB= c(.11,.2,.13,.4,.32,.33, NA)
desired = data.frame(sibA, sibB, mum, inbredCoeffsibA, inbredCoeffsibB)
desired
#   sibA sibB  mum inbredCoeffsibA inbredCoeffsibB
# 1    1   11   aa            0.10            0.11
# 2   12    2   bb            0.12            0.20
# 3    3   13   cc            0.30            0.13
# 4   14    4   dd            0.14            0.40
# 5   22   32 <NA>            0.22            0.32
# 6   23   33 <NA>            0.23            0.33
# 7    6   16 <NA>              NA              NA
```

(Ideally the merge would also work if variable *mum* was a numeric.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pmin` and `pmax` to reorder the keys, then use `merge(..., all=TRUE)`:

```
df1$k1 <- pmin(df1$sibA, df1$sibB)
df1$k2 <- pmax(df1$sibA, df1$sibB)
df2$k1 <- pmin(df2$sibA, df2$sibB)
df2$k2 <- pmax(df2$sibA, df2$sibB)
merge(df1, df2, by=c("k1","k2"), all=TRUE)

  k1 k2 sibA.x sibB.x  mum sibA.y sibB.y inbredCoeffsibA inbredCoeffsibB
1  1 11      1     11   aa      1     11            0.10            0.11
2  2 12      2     12   bb     12      2            0.12            0.20
3  3 13     13      3   cc      3     13            0.30            0.13
4  4 14      4     14   dd     14      4            0.14            0.40
5  6 16      6     16 <NA>     NA     NA              NA              NA
6 22 32     NA     NA <NA>     22     32            0.22            0.32
7 23 33     NA     NA <NA>     23     33            0.23            0.33
```